# Balance should not be zero on this address I suppose

Tags: transactions, balances

for address

https://ropsten.etherscan.io/address/0x00916c608868c68f4cd8bea6786ab40b24b55392

balance is shoving 0

[image]

but from transactions it should be little more than one ether

I believe there is simple explanation but I cant figure it out

Answer (score 1):

The balance is correct, your outgoing transaction paid over 1 ETH in fees.

Comment: as I said, there is simple explanation